# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'B.uid' in 'order clause'

Tags: php, mysql, jqgrid

I am trying to add the search toolbar to my jqGrid but running into this Column not found error. Here is the php code.

```
<?php
require_once '../jq-config.php';
// include the jqGrid Class
require_once ABSPATH."php/jqGrid.php";
// include the driver class
require_once ABSPATH."php/jqGridPdo.php";
// Connection to the server
$conn = new PDO(DB_DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
// Tell the db that we use utf-8
$conn->query("SET NAMES utf8");

// Create the jqGrid instance
$grid = new jqGridRender($conn);
// Write the SQL Query
$grid->SelectCommand = "select    A.email ,
                                  A.first_name ,
                                  A.last_name ,
                                  A.dob ,
                                  B.uid ,
                                  B.profile_name ,
                                  B.rating ,
                                  B.status 
                           from B join
                                A
                           on
                                B.uid = A.uid";
// Set the table to where you add the data
$grid->table = 'B';
$grid->setPrimaryKeyId('uid');
// Set output format to json
$grid->dataType = 'json';
// Let the grid create the model
$grid->setColModel();

// Set the url from where we obtain the data
$grid->setUrl('grid.php');
$grid->addCol(array(
    "name"=>"actions",
    "formatter"=>"actions",
    "editable"=>false,
    "sortable"=>false,
    "resizable"=>true,
    "fixed"=>false,
    "width"=>100,
    "formatoptions"=>array("keys"=>true)
    ), "first");
$grid->setColProperty('uid', array('editable'=>false, 'label'=>"Reader ID", 'search'=>false));
$grid->setColProperty('email', array('editable'=>true, 'label'=>"Reader Email"));
$grid->setColProperty('first_name', array('label'=>"Reader First Name",'search'=>true));
$grid->setColProperty('last_name', array('label'=>"Reader Last Name"));
$grid->setColProperty('profile_name', array('label'=>"Reader Profile Name"));
$grid->setColProperty('rating', array('label'=>"Reader rating"));
$grid->setColProperty('dob', 
        array("formatter"=>"date","formatoptions"=>array("srcformat"=>"Y-m-d H:i:s", "newformat"=>"Y-m-d"), "label"=>"Reader DoB"));
$statuValue = array("approved"=>"Approved", "disabled"=>"Disabled", "created"=>"Created");
$grid->setColProperty('status', array('edittype'=>'select', 'label'=>"Reader Status"));
$grid->setSelect('status', $statuValue, false, true, false, array("approved"=> "Approved"));
// This command is executed after edit
$cid = jqGridUtils::GetParam('uid');
$firstName = jqGridUtils::GetParam('first_name');
$lastName = jqGridUtils::GetParam('last_name');
$email = jqGridUtils::GetParam('email');
$dateOfBirth = jqGridUtils::GetParam('dob');
// This command is executed immediatley after edit occur.
$grid->setAfterCrudAction('edit', "update A set A.first_name=?, 
                                                           A.last_name=?,
                                                           A.email=?,
                                                           A.dob=?
                                                           where A.uid=?",
                                                           array($firstName,$lastName,$email,$dateOfBirth,$cid));

$grid->setGridOptions(array(
    "rowNum"=>100,
    "rowList"=>array(100,150,200),
    "sortname"=>"B.uid",
    "width"=>1200,
    "height"=>400
));

$grid->toolbarfilter=true;
$grid->setFilterOptions(array("stringResult"=>true));

$grid->setColProperty('first_name',array("searchoptions"=>array("sopt"=>array("cn"))));

$grid->renderGrid('#grid','#pager',true, null, null, true,true);
$conn = null;
?>
```

Whenever I search a column for a specific value, get the SQL error. Here is the firebug details:

```
    _search true
filters {"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"first_name","op":"cn","data":"Hello"}]}
nd  1305657475487
oper    grid
page    1
rows    100
sidx    B.uid
sord    asc
```

Comment: To get the best help, you should post your code directly here on SO rather than at pastebin.  Many potential answerers will be put off by having to view it on another site, and may just move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was provided with answer on the TriRand jqGrid forum itself:

http://www.trirand.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=1404